# How should I stop my cilantro plant from falling over?

Tags: herbs, cilantro

We’ve had this cilantro plant growing around the beginning of this year, it’s doing the best out of all the herbs growing at my house. However, recently it’s started to fall over, I’ve tried giving it water from a spray bottle to make sure it’s receiving enough moisture, I’ve left it out in sunlight for a longer period, but it hasn’t held itself up. Has it grown too large and need something to hold it up now? Or should I transfer it to a Slightly bigger pot to allow the roots to spread out some more? From what I know, the current pot it’s in has a 7 inch diameter and is about 5 inches deep. We have another one that’s 8 inches in diameter and 5 inches deep, and one thats 11 inches in diameter and 10 inches deep, however we were hoping to save that one for a habanero plant we’ve started growing. Any suggestions would be appreciated! I’m still new to all this gardening business and want to make sure I’m giving my plants the best treatment.

Comment: Link for image didn’t post, here it is! https://imgur.com/W9qBQKo

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it needs a bigger pot, but cilantro grown indoors does lean over, usually towards the light, and yours probably isn't getting enough light if that's where it usually lives. I can see what looks like a couple of roots on the surface of the soil - if that's what they are and they're attached to the plant, they should be in the soil. If the plant has been in the same pot since the beginning of this year, I cannot think of a reason why there should be two roots sitting on top of the soil though, but if you can without damaging the main roots, try to bury those in the soil. Otherwise, move it close to the window and rotate it daily, or cut off the top 1-2 inches to encourage new, hopefully more upright growth from the base.

Comment: We usually have it against the window, but i do realize that it’s not getting the most sunlight out of the day, would leaving it outside be a bad thing? I can definitely adjust my daily schedule to bring it outside and back inside if that’s what it needs along with any other plants that may need it.

Comment: It's only  a good idea to do that as part of a hardening off process, as in when you're intending to move it outside permanently - moving it in and out daily ongoing often causes more trouble than just keeping it indoors, not least because of sudden, full sun exposure (UVB rays don't get through glass, only UVA rays do). If outdoor temperatures are adequate, you could try hardening it off over a week or so to leave it outdoors all the time.

Comment: Got it, as far as the little root-looking parts, those were just parts of the cilantro that died off a few days ago, I forgot to remove them. Thanks for all your help! I am considering leaving it outside eventually, if that were the case, would leaving it outside in its pot matter? Or is it recommended to plant it in-ground?

Comment: No, you can keep it in a pot, though you may need to move it into a bigger one a bit later - also remember to keep it well watered, possibly daily.

Comment: Got it, thanks again for all your help! I really appreciate it :)